# Which process does Windows UMDF driver dll runs in?

Tags: windows, driver, umdf

I use a Windows' `UMDF` driver together with its `CoInstaller`. And I add some log in the CoInstaller.dll and it shows that CoInstaller.dll runs in `mmc.exe` process, which should be `Microsoft Management Console`.

But I'm not sure whether the driver.dll itself also runs in mmc.exe too?
Anyone knows that?

Comment: inside *wudfhost.exe*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/umdf-driver-host-process